# Why is iOS location service causing the app to be on for so long?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios

In iOS's Settings > Battery I can see that my app's background use is almost 100% of the time the phone is on when traveling.

My app does indeed subscribe to the `CLLocationManager.LocationsUpdated` event. But it does VERY little work there. Even if I were to tell it to update every meter (which I don't) and even if I would travel 100km with it, that would only be called 100k times. (it actually would be called only around 10k times, but we'll ignore that for now.) If I were to make a loop for 100k times doing the work it does on every call, it wouldn't even be noticeable to a user.

So how does the app use SO much time?

Comment: If you have "best" location active then you will get an update every second

Comment: @Paulw11 Not unless I move at least a meter. (Though I think there is a _maximum_ of around every 1/10 of a second.)

Comment: You can use energy logging to track actual energy use by your app. This is more accurate than what is reported in battery settings. The battery settings screen just reflects over what period your app had some activity in the background. It doesn't mean that your app was running 100% of the time in the background, if you follow me.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MonitorEnergyWithInstruments.html

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. I wonder if this can be done from Visual Studio on a PC. (I'm using the Mac only as a build server for the PC.)

Comment: The energy logs are collected in the device itself using the settings shown in the linked article. You will need to use Instruments on a Mac to analyse the log.